# Assigning a hostname to a virtual Windows XP machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, hostname

I want to access a virtual Windows XP machine from the Ubuntu 11.04 host it is running on.  Because the virtual machine gets a new IP every time it is rebooted, I would like to access it by a host name.  However, after assigning the name "selenium-xp" in the System Properties -> Computer Name section, I'm still unable to ping it from my Linux host ...

```
selenium@selenium-chi:~$ ping selenium-xp
ping: unknown host selenium-xp
```

Is there a way to assign a name to the virtual machine so that I can always access it from its Linux host?

Thanks, - Dave

ps - Because the IP changes, creating an /etc/hosts entry requires continual maintenance, and I want to go down the maintenance-free route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did with my VirtualBox install, was to add a second network adapter, which is set to 'host-only'.  The IP for this adapter doesn't change, so you can then set it in your hosts file and never have to worry about it changing.

Comment: I still want my Virtual Machine to talk to the outside world -- can I do that from a host-only adapter?  Also, when I go to Network Adapters, only 1 (Adapter 1) is editable, so it doesn't appear I have the option to add a second one.

Comment: Keep your first adapter the way you have it right now. That way you can get to the outside world. To add an adapter, you need to power off your VM, then you will be able to add a second adapter, which needs to be set to host-only.